# Is it possible to create RavenDB map-reduce index that contains generic type via IndexCreation.CreateIndexes?

Tags: ravendb

I have an index:

```
public class TotalsIndex<TClass> : AbstractIndexCreationTask<TClass, Totals> where TClass : class, IClass
```

I get an error: `Cannot create an instance of Raven.Client.Documents.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask`1[TDocument] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.'`

when use `IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(assembly, store);`

Is it possible to create RavenDB map-reduce index that contains generic type via IndexCreation.CreateIndexes?

On the other hand `new TotalsIndex<TClass>().Execute(documentStore);` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to define a **Map** or a **Map-Reduce** index is **without** the generic on the index class name.

e.g., see this Map-Reduce index example:
(taken from https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/map-reduce-index)

```
public class Employees_ByCountry : 
    AbstractIndexCreationTask<Employee, Employees_ByCountry.IndexEntry>
{
    public class IndexEntry
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int CountryCount { get; set; }
    }
            
    public Employees_ByCountry()
    {
        Map = employees => from employee in employees
            select new IndexEntry
            {
               Country = employee.Address.Country,
               CountryCount = 1
            };
                
        Reduce = results => from result in results
            group result by result.Country into g
            select new IndexEntry
            {
                Country = g.Key,
                CountryCount = g.Sum(x => x.CountryCount)
            };
    }
}
```

You can then **deploy the index** by:

```
new Employees_ByCountry().Execute(store);
```

or by:

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(new[] { new Employees_ByCountry() }, store);
```

or - as you wanted - by:

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(assembly, store);
```

or by:
Sending a `PutIndexesOperation` on the store

---

See **Creating & Deploying**:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/indexes/creating-and-deploying

Comment: https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-22004/Provide-a-better-exception-that-generic-index-is-not-supported

Comment: Danielle, thanks a lot for the detailed answer and fast reaction. Some comments on the issue you have created: I was able to avoid the error "Index name is not permitted" by the overriding IndexName like this: public override string IndexName => nameof(TotalsIndex<TClass>);